# Type key value as variant number typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, smartcontracts, web3js, abi

I have a problem to type an abi key "5777" in typescript.
When i get a netwotkId and then set in networks key, the linter show me the next error

[image]

i need to type "networkId" and that it is not a always a fixed value as like "5777"

```
let networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
```

```
// type network = "5777";

let networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();

DeluxerContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
      artifact.abi,
      artifact.networks[networkId].address
);
```

This is not a viable solution because the networkId is variable.

```
    type network = "5777";

    let networkId: network = await web3.eth.net.getId();

    DeluxerContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
      artifact.abi,
      artifact.networks[networkId].address
    );
```

Comment: `let networkId: network = await ...`

Comment: `artifact.networks[networkId as keyof typeof artifact.networks].address`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `artifact.networks[networkId as network].address`

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because `web3.eth.net.getId()` return value might be `undefined` (add logic based on return value) . You should add a guard

```
let networkId=await web3.eth.net.getId()
// continue if networkId exists
if (networkId){
  DeluxerContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
      artifact.abi,
      artifact.networks[networkId].address
);
}
```